# Google Cloud Run - How to mount FileStore / NFS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Our application requires the presence of data on two filestores. On our current Kubernetes configuration, we use a persistent volume like so:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: fileserver-input
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1T
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    path: /mypath
    server: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Which we then add as a volume in our deployment:

```
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /mypath
        name: my-path
```

How can this be accomplished with `Cloud Run on GKE`? We have tried running commands to mount the filestore in the docker container, but we have not had success because the container does not run as privileged.

Is there a way to either specify a volumeMount like on regular `GKE`, or to run the container in privileged mode in `Cloud Run on GKE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **- -container-privileged** flag to run a container with runtime privilege.

Run command similar to below:

```
gcloud compute instances create-with-container busybox-vm \
   --container-image docker.io/busybox:1.27 \
   --container-privileged
```

Remember to change image to your own.

More information you can find here: [gcloud-containers](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Is there a way to mount/run as privileged in a fully managed instance of Cloud Run?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand as of now it is not yet supported:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/using-gcp-services

Answer (score 0):

We just added support for network file systems to Cloud Run. Here's the documentation:

Filestore: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-filestore
Cloud Storage FUSE: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-fuse
Other: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/using-network-file-systems